# Cannot convert BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

I'm building a game, and I'm using MongoDB to store the players coordinates. I was using an older version of MongoDB, and my code worked fine, but I had to host the database on MongoDB Cloud, and I was forced to change the .NET version to 4.X. I downloaded the new drivers, and I'm having some issues fixing my code, because the version I was using was too old, and everything changed.

That's my code:

```
public class Coordinate {
    public float x  { get; set; }
    public float y  { get; set; }
    public float z  { get; set; }
}

public class Scores  {
    [MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes.BsonElement]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public Coordinate[] Coordinates { get; set; }
    public string Player { get; set; }
    public float Time { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
}

public static BsonArray arr = new  BsonArray();
public static BsonArray arr2 = new BsonArray();

public static IMongoCollection<Scores>  highestScoreCollection = 
db.GetCollection<Scores>("scores");
```

I can't insert a new document, I was using InsertBatch, and I changed to insertMany.

```
            arr.Add(new BsonDocument{
                {"Coordinates", arr2},
                {"Player", "Neuer"},
                {"Time", time},
                {"Level", scene.name}
            });


            highestScoreCollection.InsertMany(arr);
```

I received this error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

And I can't iterate my collection:

```
foreach (var document in highestScoreCollection.Find(new QueryDocument("Level", scene.name)).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("Time"))){

}
```

I receive this errors:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>
> error CS0103: The name 'SortBy' does not exist in the current context

How can I fix my code?

Comment: You don't need a `BsonArray`, you just need `List<BsonDocument>`, or any other `IEnumerable<BsonDocument>` implementer.

Answer (score 0):

how does the following code look to you? if it looks attractive, have a look at the mongodb driver wrapper [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities). it simplifies mongodb access quite a lot. there is absolutely no need to use `Bsondocument` at all unless you really need to.

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        [Name("Scores")]
        public class Score : Entity
        {
            public Coordinate[] Coordinates { get; set; }
            public string Player { get; set; }
            public float Time { get; set; }
            public string Level { get; set; }
        }

        public class Coordinate
        {
            public float x { get; set; }
            public float y { get; set; }
            public float z { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            var coords = new[] {
                new Coordinate{ x=1.111f, y=2.222f, z=3.333f},
                new Coordinate{ x=1.111f, y=2.222f, z=3.333f},
                new Coordinate{ x=1.111f, y=2.222f, z=3.333f}
            };

            (new[] {
                new Score
                {
                    Coordinates = coords,
                    Player = "player 1",
                    Time = 0.11f,
                    Level = "scene a"
            },  new Score
                {
                    Coordinates = coords,
                    Player = "player 2",
                    Time = 0.22f,
                    Level = "scene a"
                }
            }).Save();

            var scores = DB.Queryable<Score>()
                           .Where(s => s.Level == "scene a")
                           .OrderByDescending(s => s.Time)
                           .ToArray();

            foreach (var score in scores)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"player: {score.Player}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[disclaimer: i'm the author of the library]

Comment: Completely useless to use an entire wrapper for something like this.

Comment: @Skami well mate, the point is to show people there are other, much simpler/ elegant ways to get things done. my personal belief is that official driver is cumbersome to work with, among it's other limitations.

Comment: The question wasn't how can I do this simpler or more elegant. It was about a problem in his code. Which you didn't solve, instead you just offered a complete solution using some wrapper that you wrote yourself. Instead of explaining what the problem was. Are you sure you aren't just here to advertise your wrapper (looking at your post history, you are), cause if so you might want to look [here](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising)

Comment: This solution may work but i'm not searching for a totally new solution for my problem, it should be easier to solve the problem just changing some variable types, than using a totally new solution